# Unknown padding / margin coming out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BTYA7/4/

At the bottom of the white input box we can see that there is about 5px of padding / margin between the border and the white box. I have tried to use chrome developer tools but I cant see where it is coming from, can anyone help me pinpoint it?

It seems to be on this:

```
<div class="uEditor" style="">
```

But in the metric window there is no padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of the **line-height** property .. Set it to 0

```
.uEditor
{
    line-height: 0;
}
```

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BTYA7/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `line-height` to 0 as Sushanth suggested. But `line-height` is inheritable so you would have to change it back to normal value for the child elements.

Therefore I suggest you change the background colour on the `.uEditor` to white and leave the `line-height` unchanged.

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTYA7/8/).